# CSS rotate cutting off table in Chrome

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

So I've been tinkering with this issue that seemed to show up out of the blue. I can't seem to find any related issues, so it may just be with the last Chrome update, but I wanted to make sure that I wasn't missing anything obvious.

[image: example]

When I attempt to take a table element and rotate it backwards using rotateX(45deg) as an example, it will cut off the right side of the grid. This cutting off continues as I decrease the rotation, until 20deg where it stops. Changing the rotation is the only way to resolve the issue that I've found so far.

Here's an [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ChaseIngebritson/pen/zEjQgm) where it's getting cut off. This is the section that is rotating the table:

```
.perspective-table {
    width: 200%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -50%;
    background-color: black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    position: absolute;

    -webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg);
    transform: rotateX(45deg);

    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 30px 3px #cc39e0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 30px 3px #cc39e0;
    box-shadow:0 0 30px 3px #cc39e0;
}
```

Thanks in advance and let me know if anything needs to be changed or removed from the post!

EDIT: I tested this on a PC (1920x1080) in Chrome since the time of the post and wasn't encountering the issue. So that might part of the cause.

Specs:

- Chrome (v62.0.3202.62)
- MacOS 2560 x 1600 (v10.12.5)

Comment: your codepen seems to work fine, am using chrome

Comment: I tested a bit on my PC and was unable to recreate the issue, so this might be related to my specific resolution or the Mac version of Chrome.

Updated the post with some relevant specs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like the issue resolved itself. It was possibly a bug caused by Chrome 62 (Oct. 17th) and resolved in Chrome 63 (Dec. 5th).

If anyone else is coming across this issue, try updating your web browser.